# Even after layer is removed from a map popup remains open at the same place - ArcGIS 4.x

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Am using ArcGIS 4.x to draw a map. On button click, a feature layer is added. Popup template is initialized and added along with it. Now when I click on one of the features a popup opens displaying the layers features. Then a button is clicked for removing the layer. The layer is removed but the popup remains open at the same place.

Code for adding a layer : `map.add(layer);`
For popup I use `popupTemplate`.
Code for removing the same layer: `map.remove(layer);`

In 4.x is popuptemplate (infoWindow in 3.18) the right way to open a popup on layers ? How to make popup close automatically on map.remove(layer) ? I have already tried view.popup.close. It does not work.